# Remote Access disabled upon restart

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 installed on a desktop I use as a Media/Data/Backup server, and I've always had the problem that when it undergoes any abrupt shutdown, either due to power failure, or force shutdown due to freeze or crash, I am unable to start it back up using Remote Connection. I normally administer it using a laptop, since I don't need a monitor/keyboard as it doesn't normally see use. Even shutdowns using the remote shutdown command get buggy at times, and I need to hook up a screen to log in locally before remote access gets enabled again. How do I configure it to always be available for remote access, so I can ditch my monitor/keyboard?

Comment: Are you talking about starting it up remotely from hard off? If that's the case, then you'll need to investigate the Wake-on-Lan capability of your motherboard/NIC.

Comment: No, I can physically access the desktop, and press the power button to turn it on. What i mean is that once it boots, I need to remotely log in and start the programs that run the streaming service for example, and that remote log in does not work if the shutdown was abrupt. I need to manually log in on the desktop, and not thru my laptop.

Comment: To add to Michael Frank, you should also look at your BIOS to power on the machine inthe event of a power loss (and subsequent restoration). If the machine crashes I think this needs some attention as it shouldn't. Yes, it happens, but how frequently? If it's a few times a year (ignoring power cuts) then this is a problem. Could you have it restart on a schedule to allow it to refresh RAM and other services? To at least alleviate the inability to control the machine remotely when it freezes...?

Comment: I would assume that there is some group policy or something set up by your admin that disables remote access on every reboot. Does the issue still happen when you do a normal restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On several occasions, remote desktop does not correctly enabled in the firewall exception settings for the RDP port (3389). Check whether the port is enabled in inbound and outbound rules (Control Panel > Firewall Settings > Advance Settings). To isolate the issue, please turn off the firewall and, reboot the machine and check.

For proper shutdown, always use the /admin option when starting a remote session using mstsc, that will initiate proper reboot, or use the 'shutdown' command from your laptop to do the reboot.

Hope this helps.